# looking for multi-language code snippet html formatter (syntax highlighter)

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, formatting

I've been having trouble finding a library to display code syntax like SO does.  I'm really not 100% sure what keywords to be searching for.  It needs to be able to handle any language (possibly by adding modules) and be free.

I'd prefer libraries in either php or javascript/css as those are what my app is written in.

Also, it would be awesome if there was an open-source project or something similar where I would be able to build on the code lexer.

Comment: Keywords: http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+php+syntax+highlighter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Comment: I think this is really the best you can use right now. Do also look into the autoloading features this library offers. Oh and there is also a hosted version of the libraries which is really handy: http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/hosting.html

Answer (score 2):

There are a few:
http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/ (JS)
http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ (JS)
http://qbnz.com/highlighter/ (PHP)